# Showing data in sqlite human readable

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running sqlite on a windows machine and I have 17 columns in my schema.

I would like to show them human readable, however, when doing `.mode column` and `.headers on`, the data is so large that it cannot display nicely in my window.

Any recommendation, what I could do to show the data nicely in my window?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Chose which columns to view. (Maybe not all 17 columns are of interest every time.)

Comment: Consider using some SQLite GUI, for example [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com)

Comment: If you want to avoid installing software, buy a larger monitor.